# How to vertically center `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` in a table cell?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

How to vertically center `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`  in a table cell?

[image]

### Minimal Code (I cannot minimize anymore)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,calc,amsmath}

\newcolumntype{A}[1]{%
    >{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}\vspace{\tabcolsep}}%
    c%
    <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*2{A{0.5}|}}
\hline
\begin{equation}
  \sin x \cos x = y
\end{equation}
& \hrulefill \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm repeating myself, please don't make your code so compact that it becomes obscure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get correct spacing, put a `\strut` before and after the display, and give the two `shortdisplayskip`s the same value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,calc,amsmath}

\tabcolsep=1pt
\arrayrulewidth=1pt

\newcolumntype{A}[1]{%
    >{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}\vspace{\tabcolsep}}%
    c%
    <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*2{A{0.5}|}}
\hline
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
\strut
\begin{equation}
  \sin x \cos x = y
\end{equation}
\strut
& \hrulefill \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

You can change the `shortdisplayskip`s according to your needs; negative values are possible, too.

[image]

Comment: Your solution looks like a magic.

Comment: @xport: See my updated answer; this is a lot clearer, I think.

Comment: I just checked it and it really makes the displayed equation get vertically centered. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,calc,longtable,ragged2e}

\tabcolsep=1pt
\arrayrulewidth=1pt

\newcolumntype{A}[1]{>{%
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayskip=0pt
  \Centering}m{#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*2{A{0.5}|}}\hline
\begin{equation}
  \sin x \cos x = y
\end{equation}
& foo \hrulefill \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this. I am attempting to make use of your setting on my original setting (using `minipage`).

Comment: I just realized that your answer does not exactly center the displayed equation vertically. But Hendrik's answer does. Sorry. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `\begin{longtable}{|*2{m{0.5\linewidth}|}}`? I cannot see the advantage of column type `A` here.

Comment: @Leo, You should not make a question in answer form. :-)

Comment: @xsport: That was not a real question, it was more an answer and it is correct.

Comment: @xport: this is a valid answer to the problem (although I can’t judge whether it’s *correct* …).

Comment: @xport: If you look into the answer, you'll find that @Herbert's answer is nearly the same as this one. The key to this question is to use `m` column type. And the calculation you used seems too complex, so I just skipped them.

Comment: @Leo: Do you notice that the displayed equations in `m{}` will not be vertically centered?

Comment: @xport: Alright, I missed it. You can just add a `\null` or `\leavevmode` to solve that. (I wonder if it is accurately correct.) @Herbert's solution is still somewhat too complex for me.