# Without using `\fboxsep` method, how to make a cell has 4 equal paddings?

Tags: tables, spacing

## Scenario

Plese see the screenshot below. The top table is produced using `minipage`-typed column and the bottom table is produced using `m{}`.

**WITHOUT** using `\fboxsep` approach (that was already answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8461/how-to-make-4-equal-paddings-left-right-top-bottom-in-a-table-cell/8498#8498)), how to modify the bottom table such that it looks like the top table?

---

## Screenshot

[image]

---

## Minimal Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,calc,longtable}

\tabcolsep=5mm
\arrayrulewidth=2pt

\newcolumntype{A}
{
     >{\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}%
     \vspace{\tabcolsep}\centering}%
    c%
    <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%   
}

\newcolumntype{B}
{
     @{}>{\centering}%
    m{0.3\linewidth-0\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}%
    <{}@{}%
}

\def\pic{\rule{2.5cm}{1cm}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*2{A|}}\hline
\pic & \pic \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{|*2{B|}}\hline
\pic & \pic \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need only _one_ column type for all your examples? Where is the problem to use A für something and type B for math, type C for math with align, and type D for ...??

Comment: @Herbert: This question is related to your and @Leo's comment in another question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8437/how-to-vertically-center-beginequation-endequation-in-a-table-cell/8445#8445). Shortly speaking, I want to remove `minipage`-typed column if `m{}` can produce the same output. Creating distinct column type for each column (as you said above) has already been considered recently. :-)

Comment: And why, exactly, did this beg *another* question? It is redundant. Excess.

Comment: @morbusg, I want to remove `minipage` and change it to `m{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,calc,longtable,varwidth}

\tabcolsep=5mm
\arrayrulewidth=2pt

\newcolumntype{A}
{
     >{\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}%
     \vspace{\tabcolsep}\centering}%
    c%
    <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%   
}

\newsavebox\TBox
\newlength\THeight
\newlength\TWidth

\newenvironment{saveTBox}[1][0.5\linewidth]
  {\begin{lrbox}{\TBox}\varwidth{#1}}
  {\endvarwidth\end{lrbox}%
   \THeight=\ht\TBox \advance\THeight by \dp\TBox \advance\THeight by 30pt
   \TWidth=\wd\TBox\advance\TWidth by 30pt
   \minipage[c][\THeight][c]{\TWidth}\centerline{\usebox\TBox}\endminipage}

\newcolumntype{B}{@{}>{\saveTBox}c<{\endsaveTBox}@{}}


\def\pic{\rule{2.5cm}{1cm}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*2{A|}}\hline
\pic & \pic \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{|*2{B|}}\hline
\pic & \pic \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Herbert, why does it become more complicated? Actually I am interested in changing `minipage`-typed to `m{}`. :-)

Comment: @xport: it depends to the contents. If the contents has is no displayed or has no linebreaks it can be done easier as already posted multiple times.

Comment: @Herbert, thanks for this solution. Tomorrow I will revisit this again. I noticed the column width expands automatically that might break my real scenario.

Comment: @Herbert: There is one thing that looks "strange", i.e., the equation number gets displaced to the left from the original position. Is there a trick to make the equation number still in the correct position?

Comment: @xport: columntype A or B? The align environment works only for cilumntype A

Comment: @Herbert: In column type B of course.